# OS X (Unix, Linux): Find files with a space in the name, copy and rename them, and move them to a separate folder

Tags: linux, macos, unix, command-line

Google Music Beta won't upload mp3's with spaces in the actual filename. I would like a script that will find all the ones that have a space in the filename and copy them, rename them (just remove the spaces, or replace with underscore), and put them in a new directory so that it doesn't screw up my iTunes library. Thanks in advance! Also, i am running OS X.

Comment: In case you're seeking to do auto-imports, search for AppleScripts that add to iTunes library, eg http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-61707.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember if Perl comes installed on OS X by default, but if you have it, you can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/802187) to clean up your file names.  Right now, it removes parentheses and apostrophes, and converts everything to lower case.  You can add the line

```
$ARGV[$argnum] =~ s/ //g;
```

to remove spaces, or

```
$ARGV[$argnum] =~ s/ /_/g;
```

to convert spaces to underscores.

Save the script to your MP3 directory, then call the following from the command line:

```
./cleanmp3.pl *.mp3
```

Comment: okay, but I need the converted file to be put in a seperate directory. There are 150 of them buried in 17,000 mp3's

Comment: @tomwolber you can move the files first with: `find . -type f -name '* *' -exec mv {} /dest/dir/ \;` then run the cleanup

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls 
IAmAFile.mp3  I am a file with spaces in my name.mp3  IAmAnotherFile.mp3  I am another file with spaces in my name.mp3
```

Renaming them in a for loop...

```
$ for file in *mp3; do mv -i "$file" `echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g'`; done
mv: `IAmAFile.mp3' and `IAmAFile.mp3' are the same file
mv: `IAmAnotherFile.mp3' and `IAmAnotherFile.mp3' are the same file
```

... results in:

```
$ ls
IAmAFile.mp3  I_am_a_file_with_spaces_in_my_name.mp3  IAmAnotherFile.mp3  I_am_another_file_with_spaces_in_my_name.mp3
```

This works for all the files in your current working directory. It's a little ugly because mv gives an error for all the files that do *not* contain spaces, but it does it's job. The `-i` flag makes mv prompt before overwriting an existing fine, in case the underscore version already exists.